# Dispatcher.Invoke with Action to send response

Tags: c#

The main problem :

```
void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            internetAvailable = true;

            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                 richTextBox1.Text = "Checking Network Connection... [STATUS = SUCCESSFUL]";
            }));
        }
        else 
        {
            internetAvailable = false;

            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "Checking Network Connection... [STATUS = UNSUCCESSFUL]";
            }));
        }
}
```

When I used this code, I get an error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property, Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority,Delegate)

I recently saw a comment in a thread on how to see if a computer has a current internet connection though a C# form and I decided to put it to use, however I have all the references possible not to throw this error.

Here is the whole code in case you need to look over the whole thing:

```
void CheckInternetConnectivity(object state)
{
        if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
                webClient.Proxy = null;
                webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
                webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://clients3.google.com/generate_204"));
            }
        }
    }

    public delegate void NextPrimeDelegate();
    volatile bool internetAvailable = false;

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            internetAvailable = true;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                 richTextBox1.Text = "Checking Network Connection... [STATUS = SUCCESSFUL]";
            }));
        }
        else 
        {
            internetAvailable = false;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = "Checking Network Connection... [STATUS = UNSUCCESSFUL]";
            }));
        }
}
```

So it's testing the connection via a web-based client (`http://clients3.google.com/generate_204`), then if it returns successfully, it is supposed to run the delegated action however something is wrong.

Cannot post images so links :

- Close up of problem - https://imgur.com/vv47TyK
- Whole section of code - https://imgur.com/WT7OeL5

Any help would be appreciated, cheers

Comment: Given how unlikely it is that you can reference richTextBox1 without an error but not Dispatcher, my crystal ball says that you are not using WPF.  It recommends you use this.BeginInvoke() instead, a method available in a [winforms] Form.